# Dataform - getting os username

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, dataform, google-dataform

How would I get the name of the user currently logged into the system using Dataform?
I tried this:

```
const os = require("os"); 
console.log(os.userInfo().username);
```

but after typing "dataform compile" in the terminal I get this
[image]

Do you have any ideas? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get the session details on user using dataform, one option is you can use Cloud logging as mentioned here https://cloud.google.com/dataform/docs/audit-logging#viewing_logs

hope this helps

Comment: I would like to be able to use the entire "os" module that is built into Node from within Dataform. In this case, I need to get the username for other needs and not for who ran the script